# Is there any key in HKEY_CURRENT_USER which sad when user was login on pc?

Tags: windows, registry

Try to find information about user login time. Has no any events for searched time saved in windows security events. Thing that maybe registry can help me for that.

Is there any key in HKEY_CURRENT_USER which sad when user was login on pc?

Comment: Maybe `net user  username | findstr /B /C:"Last logon"` can help. EventViewer will not show logins unless you activate log of login events.